# Backbone collection default behavior

Tags: backbone.js, collections, fetch

I am using backbone and calling the collection.fetch() it seems to 
resetting the data though, while with the default behavior should be 
"intelligently merge" http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch  my question is what is the default behavior ?

Answer (score 1):

From the [1.0.0 changelog](http://backbonejs.org/#changelog):

> - Renamed Collection's "update" to *set*, for parallelism with the similar `model.set()`, and contrast with *reset*. It's now the default updating mechanism after a *fetch*. If you'd like to continue using "reset", pass `{reset: true}`.

So before 1.0.0, a `Collection#fetch` call would reset the collection but from 1.0.0 onwards the fetch does a `set` call. I'd guess that you're reading the 1.0.0 documentation but using a pre-1.0.0 version of `backbone.js`.